# Raise different exception for different condition

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to raise different exceptions for different conditions.
The first exception is to check the lastNumber == 0 and the second exception is to check the type of the variables.
I'm facing an issue while raising the second exception.

```
def divide(firstNumber, lastNumber):
try:
    firstNumber = float(input("Enter First Number : "))
    lastNumber = float(input("Enter Last Number : "))
    result = firstNumber / lastNumber
    return result   
except:
    print("Oops! That was not valid number.  Try again...")
    if lastNumber == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError("Cannot divide by zero")
except:
    if type(firstNumber) == 'str' and type(lastNumber) == 'str':
        raise ValueError("String could not convert to integer")
finally:
    print("Division on integer finished")
```

I'm getting below error:

```
File "<ipython-input-22-3fe68b862978>", line 9
if lastNumber == 0:
              ^
```

SyntaxError: default 'except:' must be last

Comment: You can't have two bare `except:`s (and should never really have even one anyways). That code will cause a `ZeroDivisionError` exception anyway though. Why try to catch an exception then rethrow the same exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def divide():
    try:
        firstNumber = float(input("Enter First Number : "))
        lastNumber = float(input("Enter Last Number : "))
        result = firstNumber / lastNumber
        return result   
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Can not divide with zero")
    except ValueError:
        print('Input should be a Real Number')
    finally:
        print("Division on integer finished")

result = divide()
if result:
    print('Division of two numbers is', result)
```